# Show that q→r based on the given information

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm a bit unsure about how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

> Given the following:
>   $$\begin{align}
> (p \wedge t) &\to (r \vee s) \\
> q &\to (u \wedge t) \\
> u &\to p \\
> ¬s&
> \end{align}$$
>   Show that $q \to r$.

Comment: What method do you have to use? Truth-tables? Proof? Truth-trees? Resolution? Other? If proofs, what rules (there are many different proof systems with different rules). And most importantly: do you have *any* ideas how to start? Surely you must have some idea ...

Answer (score 0):

> Show that $q\to r$.

What you require is a "conditional proof".    Assume $q$, derive $r$, thereby deducing that $q\to r$.

To get you started, (presuming you are familiar with Fitch style proof displays) your proof should look somewhat like this ...:

$\def\fitch#1#2{~~\begin{array}{|l}#1\\\hline #2\end{array}} \fitch{~1.~q\to (u\land t)\\~2.~u\to p\\~3.~(p\land t)\to (r\lor s)\\~4.~\neg s}{\fitch{~5.~q}{~6.~u\wedge t\quad: 1,5,\to\textsf{elimination (modus ponens)}\\~~~\vdots\\12. ~r}\\13.~q\to r}$

Fill in the missing details.

Answer (score -1):

(1) q.                    P(presuppositions)

(2) q→(u∧t).        P

(3) u∧t.                (1),(2),I

(4) u.                    (3),I

(5) t.                     (3),I

(6) u→p.               P

(7) p.                    (4),(6),I

(8) p∧t.                (5),(7),I

(9) (p∧t)→(r∨s).  P

(10)r∨s.                (8),(9),I

(11)￢s.                 P

(12) r.                    (10),(11),I

(13) q→r.              CP